python socket client not receive message from server
this is my first ever time asking a question on this site even though ive used lots of information from here, so I might not be the best at asking these
anyway, I'm trying to make a socket tkinter program that lets one user type a message and have it send back to everyone. I'm definitely not nearly done, but I have a problem where after I connect to the server and send a message then wait for the message to arrive back, but instead of it arriving back the program window freezes and stops responding. This is most likely from tkinter not being able to update due to it waiting on the socket message meaning the server cannot send the message. This is the code:
client:
# echo-client.py
import socket
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread
snd = False
win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry("365x230")
win.title("chat")
mmsg = ""
conc = False
conn = False
HOST = "192.168."  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 0  # The port used by 453 server

def savemsg(event=None):
    global mmsg
    global conc
    if conc:
        mmsg = msg.get()
        msg.delete(0,tk.END)
        snd = True
        print("test1")
        s.sendall(mmsg.encode("utf8"))
        print("test2")
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print("test3")
        if data:
            msgtxt.insert(0, (f"{data!r}"[2:-1]))
def LoginWindow():
    global lw
    global HOST
    global PORT
    global welc

    def connect(event=None):
        global HOST
        global PORT
        global welc
        global conc
        try:
            eval(portb.get())
            HOST = addb.get()
            PORT = eval(portb.get())
            if not conc:
                try:
                    s.connect((HOST,PORT))
                    conn = False
                    lw.destroy()
                    conc = True

                except ConnectionRefusedError:
                    welc.config(text="Server is not open")
                    conn = False
                except socket.gaierror:
                    welc.config(text="Invalid address!")
                    conn = False
        except:
            welc.config(text="Invalid port!")

    try:
        lw.destroy()
    except NameError:
        pass
    lw = tk.Toplevel()
    lw.geometry("300x250") 
    lw.title("connect")
    welc = tk.Label(lw, text="Connect to a server", font=("Arial", 20))
    txtf = tk.Frame(lw, height=3)
    inputf = tk.Frame(lw, height=3)
    addt = tk.Label(txtf, text="address:", height=1, width=30)
    portt = tk.Label(txtf, text="port:", height=1, width=16)
    addb = tk.Entry(inputf, width=30)
    portb = tk.Entry(inputf, width=16)
    connbtn = tk.Button(lw, text="Connect", height=1, width=6, command=connect)
    welc.pack(side="top", expand=True)
    txtf.pack(side="top", expand=True, fill="x")
    inputf.pack(side="top", expand=True, fill="x")
    addt.pack(side="left", expand=True)
    portt.pack(side="right", expand=True)
    addb.pack(side="left", expand=True)
    portb.pack(side="right", expand=True)
    connbtn.pack(side="bottom", expand=True)
    addb.insert(0, HOST)
    portb.insert(0, str(PORT))

chtxt = tk.Label(text="Chat on socket!", width=15, height=5)
sendframe = tk.Frame(win, height=3, width=10)
sndbtn = tk.Button(sendframe, text="Send!", width=10, height=1)
msg = tk.Entry(sendframe, width=50)
msgtxt = tk.Listbox(width=25, height=7)
scrl = tk.Scrollbar(win, command=msgtxt.yview)
cncb = tk.Button(text="connect", width=6, height=1)
sendframe.pack(side="bottom", expand=True)
chtxt.pack(side="top", expand=True)
cncb.pack(side="top", expand=True)
scrl.pack(side="right", expand=True, anchor="e", fill="y")
msgtxt.pack(expand=True, side="left", anchor="e")
sndbtn.pack(side="right", expand=True)
msg.pack(side="left", expand=True)
msgtxt.config(yscrollcommand=scrl.set)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
cncb.config(command=LoginWindow)
sndbtn.config(command=savemsg)
win.bind("<Return>", savemsg)
snd = False
def upd():
    global snd
    while True:
        try:
            if snd == True:    
                s.sendall(mmsg.encode("utf8"))
                print(mmsg)
                snd = False
        except UnboundLocalError:
            snd = bool
            if snd == True:    
                s.sendall(mmsg.encode("utf8"))
                print(mmsg)
                snd = False

def func2():
    global conc
    while True:
        if conc:
            data = s.recv(1024)
            if data:
                msgtxt.insert(1, (f"{data!r}"[2:-1]))
thread = Thread(target = func2, daemon=True)
thread.start()
win.mainloop()

server:
# echo-server.py

import socket
from threading import Thread

connections = []

def gethighest(nums=[]):
    h = 0
    for i in nums:
        if i > h:
            h = i
    return h


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
while True:
    print("current ip is ", socket.gethostname())
    HOST = input("address: \n")
    PORT = int(input("port: \n"))  # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)
    try:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        print("Server opened")
        break
    except:
        print("invalid!")
def connecc(conn, addr):
    with conn:
        print(f"Connected by {addr}")
        sendtoall("user connected".encode("utf-8"))
        while True:
            try:
                data = conn.recv(1024)
                if data:
                    print(data)
                    sendtoall(data)
            except ConnectionError:
                print("user disconnnected")
                break
def sendtoall(message):
    global connections
    for c in connections:
        c[0].sendall(message)
        print("sent")
while True:
    s.listen()  
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    connections.append([conn, addr, Thread(target=connecc, daemon=True, args=(conn, addr))])
    connections[len(connections)-1][2].start()

the message is supposed to be received back on the client but instead hangs the client from possibly the server code being written incorrectly or not being able to send

For the client side, you don't need to call s.recv() inside savemsg() because there is already a thread task func2() doing that. For the server side, inside sendtoall(), you need to check whether the client thread is still alive before sending message to it.

TCP is not message-based but a byte stream and has no concept of where messages start and end.  Received data must be buffered and a protocol implemented to extract whole messages from the buffer.  A simple way to do that is to use wrap the connection in a file-like object with socket.makefile, terminate each message with a newline, and use .readline() to read a single line at a time.
# echo-server.py
import socket
import threading

connections = {}

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    # make readable and writable file-like objects that decode UTF-8 as well.
    with conn, conn.makefile('r', encoding='utf8') as infile, conn.makefile('w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
        # associate each connection with its output wrapper
        connections[conn] = outfile
        sendtoall(conn, f'{addr}: connected\n')
        while True:
            try:
                data = infile.readline()
                if not data: break
            except ConnectionError:
                break
            sendtoall(conn, f'{addr}: {data}')
        sendtoall(conn, f'{addr}: disconnected\n')
        del connections[conn]

def sendtoall(conn, data):
    for c, outfile in connections.items():
        if conn == c:  # don't echo to the client that sent the message
            print(data, end='')
        else:
            outfile.write(data)
            outfile.flush()  # wrapper is buffered, make sure data is sent.

with socket.socket() as s:
    s.bind(('localhost', 5000))
    s.listen()
    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        threading.Thread(target=handle_client, daemon=True, args=(conn, addr)).start()

Here's a simple non-GUI client for testing:
import socket
import threading

def read(conn):
    with conn, conn.makefile('r', encoding='utf8') as infile:
        while True:
            data = infile.readline()
            if not data: break  # server closed connection
            print(data, end='> ', flush=True)

with socket.socket() as s:
    s.connect(('localhost', 5000))
    t = threading.Thread(target=read, daemon=True, args=(s,))
    t.start()
    with s.makefile('w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
        while True:
            try:
                message = input('> ')
            except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError):  # Handle CTRL-Z/D/C (OS-dependent)
                break  # clean exit instead of exception
            outfile.write(message + '\n')
            outfile.flush()
            if message == 'bye': break  # Explicit message for client to exit

        # tell server client is done.  Server will close other end and read thread will end
        s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
        t.join()  # wait for thread to exit cleanly

